# Is it possible to skip/ignore specific option value from being sent when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is it possible to skip/ignore specific option value from being sent when button is clicked?

**For example**:

When I select size 42 and **nike** shoes and then click on Send button, this will take me to http://example.com?size=42&shoes=nike

When I select size 42 and **all** shoes and then click on Send button, I want to skip/ignore `value="all"` from the request so it will take me to http://example.com?size=42 instead of http://example.com?size=42&shoes=all

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://example.com" method="get">
            <p>
                <select name="size">
                    <option value="42">42</option>
                    <option value="43">43</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <select name="shoes">
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <option value="nike">nike</option>
                    <option value="addidas">addidas</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Send">
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, Forms will not send disabled input/select fields. So You should validate & disable before send it,

Check The snippet,

> snippet will not show the URL, To see the URL use the network tab **OR** copy the snippet to your local

```js
function checkMyForm(){

  var shoes = document.getElementById("shoes").value;
  
  if(shoes == "all"){
  
  document.getElementById("shoes").disabled  = true;
  
  }
  
  return true;

}
```

```html
<form action="http://example.com" method="get" onsubmit="return checkMyForm()">
                <p>
                    <select name="size">
                        <option value="42">42</option>
                        <option value="43">43</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <select name="shoes" id="shoes">
                        <option value="all">All</option>
                        <option value="nike">nike</option>
                        <option value="addidas">addidas</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send">
                </p>
            </form>
```

Comment: Nice one! Thank you @Banujan Balendrakumar

Comment: I got last question. How to use this function if I would like to skip multiple select options, e.g. I have "all" in sizes, colors etc? :)

Comment: @Kris You want to use similar IF conditions. But the mythology depends on your implementation